# Woocommerce hide individual category tag from single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce products with multiple category's but I need to hide specific categories from the single product page.

So product 1 has product category 1, 2, 3 and 4. I need to hide category 2 and 4 from the individual product page.

This is because I have some categories that need to stay active as landing pages to be picked up by search engines but I dont want displayed on the product page.

I have tried this to hide cat 4 but no luck

[Hide specific category tag from product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478197/hide-specific-category-tag-from-product-page)

```
function hide_product_cat() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if(!empty($terms)){
        echo "<span class='prod_categories'>" . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count($terms), 'woocommerce' ) . " ";
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $woo_cat_id = $term->term_id; //category ID
            $woo_cat_name = $term->name; //category name
            $woo_cat_slug = $term->slug; //category slug
            if($woo_cat_id != 4 ){
                $result .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $woo_cat_slug, 'product_cat' ) . '" rel="tag">' . $woo_cat_name . '</a>, ';
            }
        }
        $result = substr($result, 0, -2) . ".";
        echo $result;
        echo "</span>";
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? What is the best way to do this? thank you

Comment: Where are you hooking this?  Also, how is `$result` defined, since you're using concatenation in your loop.

Comment: Hi Howard, honestly I dont know. I have just seen this online and thought it was the same issue. I wish i knew more to help you help me but as of now I dont. I was hoping that hiding specific list of category's from that section on the product page would be something someone has done and be like oh you add this code. But if you can point me in the right direction that would help a lot. Thanks